# Out of the bounds in C++ and undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

I know that in c++ access out of buffer bounds is undefined behaviour.
Here is example from cppreference:

```
int table[4] = {};
bool exists_in_table(int v)
{
    // return true in one of the first 4 iterations or UB due to out-of-bounds access
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (table[i] == v) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But, I can't find according paragraph in c++ standard.
Can anyone point me out on concrete paragraph in standard where such case is explained?

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.3

Comment: Doesn't apply here @RichardCritten, because `table+4` is a valid pointer. It's its indirection who invokes UB.

Comment: I'm stuck. _"Indirection through an invalid pointer value [...] have undefined behavior"_ ([1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#general-4.sentence-2)) but _"a pointer past the end of an object"_ is *not* an invalid pointer value ([2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3.2)).

Comment: Best I can offer is based on the not explicitly defined word [hypothetical](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3.sentence-12).

Comment: @YSC the fact that pointer value is valid doesn't mean you can perform indirection, I think you can add [\[expr.unary.op\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#1) and it will form an answer

Comment: there is no section that lists all ub. When standard defines "If A then X"  then "B" can be either "X" or "Y" because it is undefined.

Comment: Pretty sure [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.array#6) is the justification.  It says that element N-1 is the last object in the array, so a pointer to "object N" isn't actually pointing to an object in the array.

Comment: @YSC The standard doesn't always state what _is_ UB explicitly; many things that are not specified are implied by its omission (hence it being undefined). Forming a valid pointer doesn't mean the pointer can be dereferenced if the underlying source is not reachable. For that, something as simple as the the definition of an array may be sufficient like [\[decl.array\]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#6) which states only elements from `0` to `N-1` exist in contiguous space. Anything outside of that would be an unreachable object.

Comment: I agree with both of you (Yksisarvinen, 463035818_is_not_a_number). Which makes me unable to answer OP's question "point me out on concrete paragraph".

Comment: _"...Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior. ..."_ http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#general-4 plus [invalid pointer value](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3.4)

Comment: @NathanOliver Woth an answer IMHO.

Comment: @RichardCritten => http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3.2

Comment: @RichardCritten That first quote is for objects whose storage duration have come to an end, so I don't think that would apply. ordinarily you can't pick half of a point from an unrelated section of the standard and say it applies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's undefined behavior. We can juxtapose a couple of passages to be convinced of it. First, and I won't explicitly prove it, `table[4]` is `*(table + 4)`. We need only ask ourselves the properties of the pointer value `table + 4` and how it relates to the requirements of the indirection operator.

On the pointer, we have this passage:

> **[basic.compound]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.compound#3.sentence-8) Every value of pointer type is one of the following:
>
> - a pointer to an object or function (the pointer is said to point to the object or function), or
> - a pointer past the end of an object ([expr.add]), or
> - the null pointer value for that type, or
> - an invalid pointer value.

Our pointer is of the second bullet's type, not the first. As for the indirection operator:

> **[expr.unary.op]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.unary.op#1) The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression is “pointer to `T`”, the type of the result is “`T`”.

I hope it's obvious from reading this paragraph that the operation is defined for a pointer of the category described by the first bullet in the preceding paragraph.

So we apply an operation to a pointer value for which its behavior is not defined. The result is undefined behavior.

Comment: "I won't explicitly prove it" -> "The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`"  https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.sub

Comment: Since this is tagged language-lawyer, you might want to also include [\[decl.array\]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#6) just to explicitly prove that arrays occupy `N` contiguous storage elements numbered from `0` to `N-1` (which makes `N` the past-the-end pointer, in your above proof)

Comment: @Human-Compiler - I don't subscribe to the philosophy that LL answers should be made verbose and not separate the grain from the chaff. These passages are all that's pertinent imo. A pedantic proof of that pointer being of the second bullet is not needed. All that matters is that I demonstrated it is not of first bullet. If you disagree strongly on this stance, please vote accordingly.

Comment: If sizeof(int) is 4, given `int array[3][5];`, into which bullet category would `(int*)((char*)array + 20)` fall?  Would it be a pointer just past `array[0][4]`, or a pointer to `array[1][0]`?  If nothing specifies what would follow `table`, a just-past pointer wouldn't be a pointer to any specifiable object, but that wouldn't say anything about the scenario where a programmer knows what follows the end of an array object.

Comment: @supercat _If `sizeof(int)` is 4, given `int array[3][5];`, into which bullet category would `(int*)((char*)array + 20)` fall?_ You know it would fall into [expr.add]/6

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Are not all trivial objects supposed to be accessible as though they were arrays of character type?

Comment: @supercat I'm 100% against touching objects as though they were arrays of character type. Leave them alone.

Comment: @supercat They are, but... carefully and with the right tools. We can use a `char` array to get to `array[1][0]`, in standard C++20 (and previous versions once compilers implement the changes, since they were adopted as a DR), by relying on implicit object creation, but we need more code. However, all that has little relevance to this Q/A; to illustrate your point in this case, I think it's enough to ask if `array[0][5]` is a pointer past the end or a pointer to `array[1][0]` (since we know it's there). And the answer is that it's a pointer past the end and does not point to `array[1][0]`.

Comment: @bogdan: The C Standard was meant to codify a language that had been in use for years, and the C++ Standard is derived from that; I don't think the authors of the Standard made a systematic effort to ensure that there wouldn't be any gaps in the rules where they failed to address actions which would have been unambiguously defined in the earlier language, and which should have continued to be unambiguously defined.  In the earlier language, there was no problem with a pointer simultaneously pointing to one object and just past another, and being usable interchangeably both ways, but...

Comment: ...not all ways of creating pointers make it clear into which category any particular pointer belongs.  A model which recognizes that every chunk of storage simultaneously contains all standard-layout objects that will fit, but then limits the ways in which objects may be accessed, would better fit the language the C Standard was written to describe, and be easier to work with for programmers and compiler writers alike, than one where such objects have "implicit" lifetimes which differ from those of the containing storage.  I find bizarre the notion that the Standard should be used...

Comment: ...as a tool for compiler writers to declare that constructs whose behavior had been unambiguously defined should be recharacterized as "broken", rather than recognizing that the authors of C89 relied upon compilers that supported "popular extensions" to continue doing so, and the Standard has yet to define alternatives for those "popular extensions".

Comment: @supercat The language evolves, programming styles evolve, compilers evolve, the standard evolves. The C++ object model fits the evolving C++ language. We're not in the nineties anymore.

Comment: @supercat One correction to my comment above: I meant `array[0] + 5`, not `array[0][5]`, obviously, sorry.

Comment: @bogdan: There's no reason that things which could be easily accomplished in an older dialect of a language should be more difficult in a newer one.

Comment: @supercat There are good reasons for the rules being as they are. Anyway, I think long philosophical discussions about alternative-reality-C++ don't quite belong here; let's use chat for that. The purpose of my first comment above was to communicate that there's a standard way to do what you're asking as of C++20 (things were unclear previously), and to clarify the case of multidimensional arrays, which I think is relevant to the Q/A.

Answer (score 4):

Subscript operator is defined through addition operator. The array decays to a pointer to first element in this identical expression, so rules of pointer arithmetic apply. Indirection operator is used on the hypothetical result of the addition.

> [expr.sub]
>
> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postfix expression.
> One of the expressions shall be a glvalue of type “array of T” or a prvalue of type “pointer to T” and the other shall be a prvalue of unscoped enumeration or integral type.
> The result is of type “T”.
> The type “T” shall be a completely-defined object type.
> The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`, ...

---

In case where the array index is more than one past the last element i.e. `E2 > std::size(E1)` (which isn't the case in the example program), the hypothetical pointer arithmetic itself is undefined.

> [expr.add]
>
> When an expression J that has integral type is added to or subtracted from an expression P of pointer type, the result has the type of P.
>
> - If P evaluates to a null pointer value ... **(does not apply)**
> - Otherwise, if P points to an array element i of an array object x with n elements ([dcl.array]), the expressions P + J and J + P (where J has the value j) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element i+j of x if 0≤i+j≤n and the expression P - J points to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element i−j of x if 0≤i−j≤n. **(does not apply when i-j > n)**
> - **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

---

In case of `E2 == std::size(E1)` (which is the case in last iteration of the example), the hypothetical result of the addition is a pointer to one past the array and points to outside the storage of the array. The hypothetical pointer arithmetic is well defined.

> [basic.compound]
>
> A value of a pointer type that is a pointer ... past the end of an object represents ... the first byte in memory **after the end of the storage** occupied by the object

Access is defined in terms of objects. But there is no object there, nor is there even storage, and thus there isn't definition for the behaviour.

OK, there **might** in some cases be an unrelated object in the pointed memory address. Following note says that pointer past the end is not a pointer to such unrelated object sharing the address. I couldn't find which normative rule causes this.

> [Note 2: A pointer past the end of an object ([expr.add]) is not considered to point to an unrelated object of the object's type, even if the unrelated object is located at that address. ...

Alternatively, we can look at the definition of indirection operator:

> [expr.unary.op]
>
> The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type ... and the result is an lvalue referring to the object ... to which the expression points. ...

There is a contradiction because there is no object that could be referred to.

---

So, in conclusion:

```
int table[N] = {};
table[N] == 0; // UB, accessing non-existing object
table[N + 1];  // UB, [expr.add]
table + N;     // OK, one past last element
table[N];      // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ See CWG 232
```

Comment: "I couldn't find which normative rule causes this" - I believe it's the list of kinds of values of pointer type above the note: such a value can only be "one of the following", so a *pointer past the end of* an object is inherently not a *pointer to* an object, so it cannot *point to* an object.